# is theconstructsim real or a scam

Tags: ros, slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi all.
i have been learning ros for a while now online, and i was looking for a nice good and comprehensive course. i am sorry if this question is not appropriate but has anyone heard about theconstructsim.com?
is this a reliable site? or is this just a scam. i tried to find reviews on the courses but found none.

TIA

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/365083/is-theconstructsim-real-or-a-scam/) by [droneman1](https://answers.ros.org/users/62931/droneman1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2020-11-08

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-11-09**:
Asking "are they real or not" about the Construct, which is mostly using *simulation* to support their educational activities made me chuckle.

**Comment by [R. Tellez](https://answers.ros.org/users/22719/r.-tellez/) on 2020-11-10**:
That is a good point @gvdhoorn !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

They have a lot of free content if you are interested, at least in youtube.
I used their service for a year and it really helped a lot since I was just starting ROS. You can save a lot of time, by reusing their setup configurations for a real robot, until you know what you are doing.

---

Originally posted by [mbudris](https://answers.ros.org/users/38917/mbudris/) with karma: 56 on 2020-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [droneman1](https://answers.ros.org/users/62931/droneman1/) on 2020-11-09**:
thank you for the answer. it just seemed wired that they have almost no reviews online.
i tried it out. sadly, it has no video instructions, just text so it was not what i was looking for. i was looking for udemy style courses just more comprehensive.

**Comment by [nfry321](https://answers.ros.org/users/62999/nfry321/) on 2020-11-10**:
This is the course you are looking for: https://www.udemy.com/course/ros2-for-beginners/
I have used it and highly recommend it. Here is the website for the guy who teach the course https://roboticsbackend.com/

**Comment by [R. Tellez](https://answers.ros.org/users/22719/r.-tellez/) on 2020-11-11**:
If you prefer Udemy courses, we also have an Udemy course based on videos and a set of rosjects that you can run for free on the cloud without having to install anything on your computer, so you have the ROS environment already setup online. Check it out here: https://www.udemy.com/course/ros-basics-1/

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming you're not trolling: yes, they are *for real*.

I can't speak to whether it'll be worth it for you, as it would depend on your current skill level, but quite a lot of people have found their courses, on-line environment (Gazebo, RViz, console, editors, etc) and forum helpful while learning ROS 1 and ROS 2.

Note: this is **not** an endorsement, as I've not made use of any of their services. Just wanted to clear up the "real or not" question you posted.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-11-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [droneman1](https://answers.ros.org/users/62931/droneman1/) on 2020-11-09**:
thank you for the answer. it just seemed wired that they have almost no reviews online.
i tried it out. sadly, it has no video instructions, just text so it was not what i was looking for. i was looking for udemy style courses just more comprehensive.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-11-09**:\

> it has no video instructions

This confuses me really.

One thing the Construct is known for is having videos for just about everything. Actually to the point where I'd like to see *less* videos (I'm not a video guy, I'd rather quickly scan a bunch of text).

You may want to go back and make sure you're looking at the right site/content.

**Comment by [R. Tellez](https://answers.ros.org/users/22719/r.-tellez/) on 2020-11-10**:
In order to clarify, at The Construct we post videos showing how to do things in ROS. All our videos are for free and can be found on Youtube.

In case you want to learn by practicing, we provide you guided practical courses (which are the paid courses). Those courses are not video based but text/full-of-practice based.

We believe that practice is what really makes the ROS Developer. Videos are great because they can teach you how to do a very concrete thing at a given moment, but practice is what you need if you want to become a full ROS Developer (that is our opinion).

So we are trying to balance delivering to the community (with tons of free learning content) with having a business. Any advice on how to improve this balance is welcomed.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-11-10**:
My comment was not a critique on how you run your business Ricardo.

It was merely an observation, wrapped in a bit of hyperbole to get the point across that I was surprised by the "I can't find any videos" comment by @droneman1.

*Personally*, I don't like videos. That doesn't change the fact that for many others, videos are just fine.

**Comment by [R. Tellez](https://answers.ros.org/users/22719/r.-tellez/) on 2020-11-10**:
Really appreciated your comment @gvhoorn I liked very much your comment about the videos and found it very funny because you nailed it. Thanks for taking the time to reply

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This sounds a bit open question so I'm a bit hesitant to post as an answer.

- There was a moment the company behind theconstructsim.com was a bit aggressively using the OSS community for advertisement for their professional service.
- That said I've tried their tutorials and I found generally recommendable for new ROS learners, or even the experienced who want to know about particular domains (they seem to keep adding tutorials for new technical domains). Their tool is (or at least what I tried was) fully web-based. Really great that a learner doesn't need to set up the computer environment specific to ROS (which is very common pain points for physically hosted workshop).
- The company seems to have been [non-financially](https://roscon.ros.org/world/2020/) and [financially](https://roscon.ros.org/2019/) sponsoring ros.org's events.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2020-11-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [droneman1](https://answers.ros.org/users/62931/droneman1/) on 2020-11-09**:
thank you for the answer. it just seemed wired that they have almost no reviews online.
i tried it out. sadly, it has no video instructions, just text so it was not what i was looking for. i was looking for udemy style courses just more comprehensive.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-11-09**:\

> There was a moment the company behind theconstructsim.com was a bit aggressively using the OSS community for advertisement for their professional service.

Yeah, I agree with this part.

**Comment by [R. Tellez](https://answers.ros.org/users/22719/r.-tellez/) on 2020-11-10**:
Thank you Isaac for your answer. I'm Ricardo from The Construct and I would like to clarify just a small detail: for the ROS.org events we have been supporting them since 2017 (ROSCON in Korea). For this year, our company is *Friend of the Conference*, as you can see in [this link](https://roscon.ros.org/world/2020/#sponsors). Sorry we cannot do more as a small company.

I would also like to have the opportunity to apologize for the aggressive usage of the OSS community. Thanks to feedback like yours, we were able to correct that, and I think that at present there are no complains about that, at the same time that we are contributing to the community with many free and open resources.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Very fair question @droneman1. These days, one doesn't know what to think...

I'm Ricardo from The Construct, and I would like to explain you why we are not scam in 3 simple points:

1. We have fully free courses available that you can take from beginning to end and check if what we promise is real or not:

   - [Python for robotics](https://www.theconstructsim.com/robotigniteacademy_learnros/ros-courses-library/python-robotics/)
   - [Linux for robotics](https://www.theconstructsim.com/robotigniteacademy_learnros/ros-courses-library/linux-for-robotics/)
2. You can test for free every other course on its first unit, so you can check what the course is about. First unit contains a demo of what you will learn to do in the full course and it is fully interactive with the robot simulation.
3. We have a 30 days refund policy no questions asked.
4. (Extra point) We are charging only 39€ per month. That is too small amount to be a scam.

I hope I convinced you that we providing you a lot of evidence about the quality of our service, and that The Construct is a no risk place to learn ROS. Any question will be welcomed. You can contact me directly if you want by email at rtellez@theconstructsim.com

---

Originally posted by [R. Tellez](https://answers.ros.org/users/22719/r.-tellez/) with karma: 874 on 2020-11-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1